# ajax load method isse laravel 4

Tags: ajax, laravel-4

i have written a load method and pass the variables to the controller but the ajax is only sending the id of first selector and i have many selectors based on number of articles available in the database with the same class name.

```
$(".cb-content").load("/actions",
    {"product_id":$('.cb-content').attr('id')},function(response){
```

},'json'
        );

### controller

```
public function actions(){
    $product_id=Input::get('product_id');
    //return View::make('product')->with('product',$product_id);
    //if($product_id){}else{return Response::json(array('result'=>0));}
    $user=Auth::user();
    $count_likes=UserActionOnProduct::where(array('product_id'=>$product_id,
                                                'action_like'=>1))->count();
    $count_follow=UserActionOnProduct::where(array('product_id'=>$product_id,
                                                'action_follow'=>1))->count();

    $count_favorite=UserActionOnProduct::where(array('product_id'=>$product_id,
                                                'action_favorite'=>1))->count();
    if($user){
        $user_id=$user->id;
        $product=UserActionOnProduct::where(array('product_id'=>$product_id,
                                                'user_id'=>$user_id))->get()->first();
        //echo $product->action_like;

        return View::make('product')->with('product',$product_id);

        }else{
            return Response::json(array('result'=>0));
            }
    }
```

ajax is sending the product_id of the first product only for all products.

please help..:)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand what you want, but you need to use all element the load

[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

something

```
$(".cb-content").each().load("/actions",
    {"product_id":$(this).attr('id')},function(response){ ...
```

Comment: i used each() but getting a jquery errror. error:TypeError: b is undefined

Comment: thank you very much....I used each method with the selector and call post function within each() and now its working...:)